# Recognising an empty line from stdin in C

Tags: c, parsing, input

I'm having some hard time trying to recognise an empty line on the standard input in C. I'm having the following code:

```
char *line = NULL;
int done = 0;
while (!done) {
   scanf("%m[^\n]", &line);
   if (line != NULL)
      //do something with line
   else
      done = 1;
scanf("\n");
free(line);
```

The lines are supposed to be user's commands. Let's say that he is only allowed to call

```
insert something
delete something
```

or

```
exit
```

In any other case the program should output, let's say, "command not allowed". I can do that in every case except one - when there's an empty line on the input - I don't know how I can recognise one. I would appreciate some help on that.

Comment: If you want to read whole lines, then you're probably better off using [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead. And if you do use `fgets`, then an empty line will only contain a newline and that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the information in this answer was extracted from `man scanf`.

The `%[` format code will not match an empty string:

> `[`      Matches a **nonempty sequence** of characters from the specified set of accepted characters

Remember that `scanf` has a very useful return value:

> These functions return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an early matching failure.

You should always check the return value of scanf, because the output arguments have unspecified values if the corresponding input item couldn't be successfully matched.

In this case, the return value will tell you whether there was a non-empty string preceding the newline character.

---

As presented, your code has a memory leak (assuming that more than one line is read), because the `m` modifier causes memory to be allocated, without ever looking at the value originally stored in the corresponding argument. So if the argument held the address of previously allocated storage, it will be overwritten with the address of the newly-allocated storage and the previous allocation will leak.

The loop should be:

```
while (!done) {
  line = NULL; /* Not strictly necessary */
  if (scanf("%m[^\n]", &line) == 1) {
    /* Do something with line */
    free(line);
  } else {
    /* Handle an empty line */
  }
  /* skip trailing newline. See below. */
  getchar();
}
```

`scanf("\n")` does not only skip a single newline character. It is not different from `scanf(" ")`; any whitespace in a scanf format:

> matches  any  amount  of  white space, including none, in the input.

If you just want to skip the single newline character, use `getchar()`.

Comment: As much as I would like it to, your solution doesn't seem to work. It still skips all the empty lines. I believe the scanf function doesn't care much about the empty lines

Comment: @jytug: as I said, the scanf(" ") will skip empty lines. I replaced it in the sample code with a getchar.

Comment: @jytug: you might want to check whether getchar returned EOF. The code provided is not an answer; it's an outline.

Comment: Thank you, I just found that out by trial and error and got to the answer on my own. I appreciate your patience

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `scanf()`, used `fgets()` or *nix `getline()`.

`scanf()` is designed to read formatted data - it works marginally well with *lines*.
`fgets()` is designed to read a *line*  (0 or more characters up to and including a final `'\n'`) and converting that to a C string by appending a null character `'\0'` to the destination buffer.

```
char line[100];
while (!done) {
  // scanf("%m[^\n]", &line);
  if (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) == NULL) {
    // EOF or input error occurred, for now let us just clear line
    line[0] = 0; 
  }
  // get rid of potential trailing \n
  line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = 0;
  if (line[0]) 
    //do something with line
  else
    done = 1;
}
```

---

The `m` in `"%m[^\n]"` is not specified in the C spec.  It is an extension used by some C libraries.